# Why am I getting a NotFoundError?

Tags: sql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to make a link to another page. When I click the link, it takes me to a not found error. I don't understand why this is only happening with this specific link and not the other links on the page

I've tried changing the name of the handlebars file and also moving around the line of code

```
<a href = "/updatelabel" >View and Update Labels</a>
```

I also have a handlebars view called "updatelabel.hbs"
This is the page I want the link to lead to.

When I click the link, I get a NotFoundError that looks like this;

NotFoundError: Not Found
    at app.use (/Users/collection-manager/app.js:26:8)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/chloemeier/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/chloemeier/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/chloemeier/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/chloemeier/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/Users/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/Users/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/collection-manager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)

If someone could try to direct me to where the problem possibly is that would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

you need a route in your express app so it can respond:

```
app.get('/updatelabel', function(req,res) {
   res.render('updatelabel') 
});
```

you also need to set:

```
app.set('view engine' 'handlebars')
app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname,'/app/views'), path.join(__dirname, '/public/views')]);
```

inside your express configuration